# Multiple file upload using CocoaHttpServer or with any http server on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I used cocoaHttpserver for transferring content to iPhone in my application. But it just provides single file upload. But I saw applications which provide multiple uploads such as dropbox, mydocs. During googling i found that they are using kinda swf to perform multiple uploads. So can anyone guide me to do multiple uploads for iPhone using any existing http server or to modify cocoaHttpserver for the same. I am very new to server side programming and I have to implement multiple file uploading scheme for iPhone where iPhone would be acting as a http server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?. I have same problem and still can't find any ideas. If you figureout this problem let me know your solution.

Comment: yes I did it using FancyUpload....................... sorry for too late reply. here is the link http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [file-uploader](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader) project can help.